# Liferay Drools Sample Error

Tags: liferay, integration, tomcat7, liferay-6, drools

I'm trying to test the [sample drool portlet](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/tree/master/portlets/sample-drools-portlet/docroot) from git-hub and start learning how to work with a Drools portlet integrated in Liferay.

I m working with Liferay 6.1, Tomcat 7.

My code has an error, didn't recognise this library..

```
<%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ClassResolverUtil" %>
```

And I changed this line this line several times to avoid using this import..

```
MethodKey methodKey = new MethodKey(ClassResolverUtil.resolveByPortalClassLoader("com.liferay.portal.security.permission.ResourceActionsUtil"), "getModelResource", PageContext.class, String.class);
```

But I get the same error always:

`generator-rules-portlet-6.1.20.1.war` does not support this version of Liferay.

What can I do to solve this error??

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what version of Liferay are you running? CE? EE? I've not seen "generator-rules-portlet", where did you get it?

Comment: If I look at the info on eclipse I see: Liferay v6.1 CE. But in the folder where I placed the tomcat and the deploy folder: liferay-portal-6.1.20-ee-ga2. The folder with the plugins its 6.1.20-ee-ga2.

Comment: Liferay plugins are only tested with the same version of Liferay (even on minor versions), so you should find the matching portlet for your installation - 6.1.1 or 6.1 CE GA2 would be the latest available version on CE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have took the portlet from "master" branch of github. The master branch is 6.2 Milestone. Switch the branch to "6.1.x" and download the portlet, u will not get this error issue.

Regards,

Ramkumar.